# How to construct a Vaadin design that keeps min-dimensions, stretches when possible, shows browser-level scrollbars

Tags: java, css, vaadin

The basic visual structure of a Vaadin application that I am maintaining consists of a centered workarea that mainly consists of a TabSheet implemented menu. The inner workarea has a fixed width (at least currently).

What I am trying to achieve is:

1. The workarea should stretch to the bottom of the viewport but it should be no smaller, vertically, than, say, 400px.
2. When resizing the viewport the workarea should adapt (in horizontal position and vertical size).
3. If the viewport gets smaller than the workarea, in height or width, scrollbars should appear on the viewport (i.e. not on the workarea)
4. On iOS or Android devices the location bar should disappear. A note on this: I noticed that, unlike "normal" web sites, Vaadin applications that have computed heights seem to eagerly size down so that browsers on mobile device see no necessity to hide the location bar for more real estate.

Here is one attempt of mine:

```
public class VaadinApplicationImpl1 extends Application {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public void init() {
    setTheme("sample");
    setMainWindow(new Window() {{
      setCaption("Vaadin-Layouting Sample");
      setContent(
        new CssLayout() {{
          addStyleName("workareacontainer");
          addComponent( 
            new TabSheet() {{
              addTab(
                new VerticalLayout() {{
                  setSizeFull();
                  setSpacing(true);
                  Label l = new Label("Workarea");
                  addComponent(l);
                  setExpandRatio(l, 1.0f);
                  addComponent(
                    new HorizontalLayout() {{
                      setSpacing(true);
                      addComponent(new Button("Button 1"));
                      addComponent(new Button("Button 2"));
                    }}
                  );
                }}, 
                "First"
              );
            }}
          );
        }}
      );
    }});
  }
}
```

where

```
.workareacontainer {
    min-height: 400px;
    height: 100%;
}

.workareacontainer > div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    min-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.workareacontainer > div > div {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    bottom:5px;
    left:5px;
    right:5px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

The result is a tab sheet stretched and centered as I wanted it, but not resizing when the browser is resized. Is that a limitation of the CssLayout? Can that be overcome?

Furthermore I would only get vertical scrollbars and never horizontal ones. Any idea how to fix that?

Supposedly you can get browser level scrollbars when starting with a Panel and an inner layout of setSizeUndefined(). That only seems to work if there is no 100%-stretch requirements though.

Sorry, if this is a duplicate and I was just not able to identify a good solution from other questions.

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>As I understand your problem, you want the workarea to be dynamically centered at a percent of the browser's view dimensions, isn't? I managed to reproduce your sample and solved both the minimun-size scrollbars and the dynamic centering problem adjusting your css to the following:</strike>

---

## Update

With the following modifications the `TabSheet` resizes to adjust to the container div.

```java
public class Vaadinapplicationimpl1Application extends Application {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setTheme("sample");
        setMainWindow(new Window() {{
                setCaption("Vaadin-Layouting Sample");
                setContent(new CssLayout() {{
                        addStyleName("workareacontainer");
                        setSizeFull();
                        addComponent(new TabSheet() {{
                                // If you set the width to "100%" the TabSheet will overflows the
                                // the green and red divs. Set this to 100% and add 
                                // "overflow-x:hidden" to the CSS if you don't care about
                                // the right margin  
                                setWidth("99%");

                                addTab(new VerticalLayout() {{
                                        setSpacing(true);
                                        Label l = new Label("Workarea");
                                        addComponent(l);
                                        addComponent(new HorizontalLayout() {{
                                                setSpacing(true);
                                                addComponent(new Button("Button 1"));
                                                addComponent(new Button("Button 2"));
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }, "First");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also change your CSS file to the following:

```css
.workareacontainer {
    min-height: 400px;
    height: 100%;

    /* 
    Add a minimun width to the "workareacontainer" container div, 
    the browser will use this value when the resize event takes in
    for the minimun width calculation (as it does for the height) 
    */
    min-width: 800px;
}

.workareacontainer > div {
    height: 100%;

    /* 
    Add extra padding to the right
    so the green div shows contained inside this
    */
    padding: 5px;        
    padding-right: 30px;

    /* 
    Replace this line 
       width: 800px;
    with: 
    */
       width: 90%; 
    /* 
    Here you make the workarea adaptable to the browser's width size, 
    leaving a small gap of 5% at both margins that will make your 
    workarea look "centered" 
    */

    min-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.workareacontainer > div > div {
    /* 
    Remove the absolute positioning, add extra padding to the right
    so the TabSheet shows contained inside the div
    */
      padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;

    height:100%;
    width:100%;

    background-color: green;
}
```

Tested with Google's Chromium 30.0.1599.114 and Firefox 25.0.1 (when working with [CSSLayout](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.csslayout.html) is recommeded to test for browser compatibility).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending time on this. Considering the number of views vs. the number of comments/answers this must be harder than I hoped. I tried your suggestion, but it is not really what I asked for. The main problem is that the Vaadin parts do not adapt during resizing (#2) - while observing the other constraints. I.e. if it would always fill the workareacontainer completely (also after resizing and whether it is completely visible or not), this would probably solve most of it. I am happy to concede that CSSLayout is not the right choice btw.

Comment: So, besides the scrollbars and the dynamic center, you also want the `TabSheet` to adjust to the container div space? Or do you want the `TabSheet` and its content to proportionally adjust to de container div?

Comment: Right, it's about the TabSheet to adjust to the container div.

Comment: @gnomie I have updated my answer, now the `TabSheet` adjust to the green div when the browser is resized (keeping the scrollbars and the div centered requirements)

Comment: Ahhh perfect! After some playing around with it, I think the crucial trick is to do any of setWidth/setHeight/setSizeFull on the CSSLayout. After that it starts adapting to size changes. With that in mind I also just found http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/11193. I can have setWidht("100%") or setSizeFull on the TabSheet and it works nicely with Firefox and Chromium at least. This is indeed the behavior I was looking for. Thanks!